# Dynamically add to different JS objects data - within a loop or switch and so on?

Tags: javascript, loops, object, variables

all I am stuck at this position and don't know how to solve it :)
I am getting many different attributes from a webpage - which I want to store in 
objects to send them later to PHP/Mysql - my problem is that I don't know how much objects are created by the user which puts data into the page so I need to create objects lets say: object1{id, name, date...}, object2, object3 by the click on the send button in the page - I know that there can't be more than 150 objects at one time + data stored in the object. So I tried to create objects dynamically while reading the length of input fields - which worked so far.
Now I want to fill the created objects with data while iterating over the page with jquery and search for classes which have the id and data I need to store in Object1, Object2 and so on
My problem is that I dont know how to save data in an object within an loop

```js
var objekt1 =  {};
var objekt2 =  {};


// handle click and add class
$("#but1").on("click", function(){
 for (x=1;x<3; x++ ){
 var key = "objekt"+x;
 alert(key);
 var value = x;
 key.id=x;
 key.name="name"+x;
 }
 /*objekt1.id='10';
 objekt1.name='obj1';
 objekt2.id='20';
 objekt2.name='obj2';*/
 
 $("#output1").html(objekt1.id+ ' ' + objekt1.name);
 $("#output2").html(objekt2.id+ ' ' + objekt2.name);
}) //opn click
```

```css
#but1 {
  background: #0084ff;
  border: 1px solid white;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 8px 14px;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #fff;
}

#but1:hover{
  cursor: pointer;}
body {
  background: #20262E;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="but1">try me</div>
<div id="output1">

</div>
<div id="output2">

</div>
```

my problem which I dont know how to create is this one:
I want to achieve: objekt1.id=1;
but dont know how to create it: this doesn't work at all:
'objekt'+x=x;
but also the key value method doesn't work as expected :(
what am I doin wrong?

I know that there are also arrays for this type of problem but really multidimensional arrays work in all other languages where I can have key value pairs and not only numeric indexes ... :(

Hopefull you understand what I meant ... its really late today ...

Thanks to all out there! for your time and patience :)

Comment: Don't use separate variables. Create one object whose keys are the names. `object[1].x = x`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create `objekt1` & `objekt2` as global variables use `window["variable_name"]`

```js
for (x=1; x < 3; x++){
window["objekt" + x] = {};
window["objekt" + x].name = "name" + x;
window["objekt" + x].id = x * 10;
 }
console.log(objekt1)
console.log(objekt2)
```

Or create your own parent object and sub objects dynamically

```js
var data = {};

for (x=1; x < 3; x++){
data["objekt" + x] = {};
data["objekt" + x].name = "name" + x;
data["objekt" + x].id = x * 10;
 }
console.log(data.objekt1)
console.log(data.objekt2)
```

Answer (score 1):

I am a little unclear on what you're asking but it sounds like you are trying to dynamically create objects within a for loop. Below is an example of how to iterate over something and create an object, then store it within an array. Let me know if my understanding is incorrect.

```js
// Option 1
const objects = [];
for (let x = 1; x < 3; x++ ){
   const obj = {
    id: x,
    name: `something ${x}`
   }
   objects.push(obj);
 }
 console.log(objects);
 
 
 // Option 2
 const obj2 = {};
 for (let x = 1; x < 3; x++) {
  obj2[`Item_${x}`] = { id: x };
 }
 console.log(obj2);
```